# Is this possible to change or set the Padding Color of a Windows Form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq

I want to change the **padding** color of my **windows form** how can i do this help me....

```
  this.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 3, 3, 3);
```

Comment: Override OnPaintBackground() and paint it any way you like.

Comment: @Hans Passant -how can i do this will you explain more..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form code:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //base.OnPaintBackground(e);  //comment this out to prevent default painting
    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Purple))  //any color you like
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.ClipRectangle);
}
```

Having set your padding, you have exposed the underlying form's background.  So just paint it with the color you want to show through.